# Typescript build on save dotnet core

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, gulp, asp.net-core

In a traditional Asp.NET MVC application, I could simply add a typescript file and visual studio would automatically compile it to .js on saving the file. The .ts files were just saved in the script folder next to the .js files and it all worked nicely.

The docs for typescript and Asp.Net Core [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/asp-net-core.html) suggest a different approach where the typescript files are saved in a different folder (which makes sense given Asp.Net Core's 'the file system is the project structure' approach). They also suggest using Gulp to have the TypeScript compiler run and the .js copied into the wwwroot folder immediately after the project is built.

Is there a way to have the TypeScript files automatically compiled whenever they are saved rather than having to run a Gulp task each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try like this-

1. Use `compileOnSave` to true, so the `.ts` gets transpiled into `.js` on each save.
2. Set the `outDir` to `wwwroot/app` so the transpiled `.js` files get saved in `wwwroot/app` folders which is served by asp.net core application.

Here is an sample of tsconfig.json-

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app",
    "strictNullChecks": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```